# Redis version on Cloudbees is out of date?

Tags: build, jenkins, redis, cloudbees

I'm setting up an OSS build in Cloudbees with `/usr/sbin/redis-server` being started as one of the build tasks:

```
+ /usr/sbin/redis-server
[204] 04 Nov 03:52:58 # Warning: no config file specified, using the default config. In order to specify a config file use 'redis-server /path/to/redis.conf'
[204] 04 Nov 03:52:58 * Server started, Redis version 2.0.3
```

The (Redis site)[http://redis.io/download] shows 2.6.2 to be the current version and 2.4.17 as "legacy".  On the extended downloads page, version 2.0.3 is deprecated.

Am I launching it the wrong server executable, or are there plans to support a more recent version of Redis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to upgrade the build machines so that packages like this can be upgraded. We will do so soon.

Answer (score 1):

CloudBees now has the latest versions of Redis (2.6.4, 2.4.17, 2.2.12) built and available using our add-on system.  This lets us offer newer versions of packages than are supported by the operating system packages.

You can find more information on this on our Redis page - https://developer.cloudbees.com/bin/view/DEV/Redis